# Showing Elevation with Cardview in Preview in Android Studio but not in Device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I was trying to make shadow effect with Cardview and it is showing the shadow effect in the XML Preview but there is no shadow effect on the Physical Device

[image: Recycler View on Device which is not showing any Cardview Effect]

[image: Preview on Android Studio which is showing the shadow effect]

Here is the code for the XML of recycler view data item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:id="@+id/cast_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image4" />

        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:id="@+id/cast_name"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:id="@+id/cast_character_name"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Sub_Title"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your `RecyclerView` is putting your cards immediately next to each other, leaving no room for the system to draw a shadow. You can actually see a tiny shadow at the top and bottom corners of your cards (because the rounded corner leaves a very small amount of space for the system to draw the shadow in).

To leave space for the shadow, you should add an `ItemDecoration` to your `RecyclerView` that sets each card's offsets.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recycler.addItemDecoration(new MyItemDecoration(this));
    ...
}

private static class MyItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int offset;

    public MyItemDecoration(Context context) {
        this.offset = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.card_offset);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.set(offset, offset, offset, offset);
    }
}
```

And define the offset you want as a dimen resource, like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="card_offset">3dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Without `ItemDecoration`:

[image]

With `ItemDecoration`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this use  `app:cardElevation` and `app:cardUseCompatPadding` like this
if required name splace than add this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing your app on Kitkat device. Try to test your app on Lollipop or later device.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
app:card_elevation="2dp"